# sphinx search MVA

Tags: php, sphinx

I'v got some sphinx.conf file where I want to add MVA

```
   sql_query = \
SELECT ps.id as id, ps.ido as ido, ps.idu as idu\
FROM products_search as ps 


sql_attr_uint = ido
sql_attr_uint = idu
sql_attr_multi = uint idattr from query \
SELECT id,idattr FROM products_attributes WHERE idoffer = ido \
```

it's possible to create sql_attr_multi with multiple ids in one filed from products_attributes with 'WHERE' clouse and 'ido' from query abowe ?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found the solution

```
sql_attr_multi = uint idattr from query;
SELECT ps.ido,pa.idattr FROM products_search as ps JOIN products_attributes as pa on ps.ido = pa.idoffer
```